# SQL Query for sum of columns based on trip

Tags: sql

I am having below table and here I need to calculate the total distance travelled. For Ex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ldgQ.png)

Here I need to calculate the total trip distance its covered from Start Location to end location. like From A to A total distance is 55 km. From E to E 41 KM. Not sure how to calculate it in SQL. Can you any one help me to give some idea to fix this.

Regards

Anand

Comment: what SQL version you use ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: SQL server 2016

Comment: you need a way to order the data by `row_number`. How would you know when one trip starts and one ends?